# How to find all lines in the csv files from the given directory that contains date which is Saturday or Sunday?

Tags: files, grep, date, csv

I have a directory that contains some csv files. I would like to find files and line numbers that contains a date that is either Saturday on Sunday. Dates are of the format dd.mm.2019. Is the following code correct? Is there any other approaches?

```
grep -n '^5.1.2019|^6.1.2019|^12.1.2019|^13.1.2019|^19.1.2019|^20.1.2
019|^26.1.2019|^27.1.2019|^2.2.2019|^3.2.2019|^9.2.2019|^10.2.2019|^16.2.2019|^17.2.2019|^23.2.2019|^24.2.2019|^2.3.2019|^3.3.2019|^9.3.2019|^10.3.2019|^16.3.2019|^17.3.2019|^23.3.2019|^24.3.2019|^30.3.2019|^31.3.2019|^6.4.2019|^7.4.2019|^13.4.2019|^14.4.2019|^20.4.2019|^21.4.2019|^27.4.2019|^28.4.2019|^4.5.2019|^5.5.2019|^11.5.2019|^12.5.2019|^18.5.2019|^19.5.2019|^25.5.2019|^26.5.2019|^1.6.2019|^2.6.2019|^8.6.2019|^9.6.2019|^15.6.2019|^16.6.2019|^22.6.2019|^23.6.2019|^29.6.2019|^30.6.2019|^6.7.2019|^7.7.2019|^13.7.2019|^14.7.2019|^20.7.2019|^21.7.2019|^27.7.2019|^28.7.2019|^3.8.2019|^4.8.2019|^10.8.2019|^11.8.2019|^17.8.2019|^18.8.2019|^24.8.2019|^25.8.2019|^31.8.2019|^1.9.2019|^7.9.2019|^8.9.2019|^14.9.2019|^15.9.2019|^21.9.2019|^22.9.2019|^28.9.2019|^29.9.2019|^5.10.2019|^6.10.2019|^12.10.2019|^13.10.2019|^19.10.2019|^20.10.2019|^26.10.2019|^27.10.2019|^2.11.2019|^3.11.2019|^9.11.2019|^10.11.2019|^16.11.2019|^17.11.2019|^23.11.2019|^24.11.2019|^30.11.2019|^1.12.2019|^7.12.2019|^8.12.2019|^14.12.2019|^15.12.2019|^21.12.2019|^22.12.2019|^28.12.2019|^29.12.2019$' *.csv
```

Comment: Two notes: the periods should be escaped if they are literal in the file (19.1.2019 should be matched with 19\.1\.2019, for example), and secondly: is there a particular field in the CSV file that contains the date? A simple `grep` could falsely match against a "note" or "description" field that happened to contain a matching date.

Comment: I tried to use the format `19\.\.2019`without success. It look like the date is on the second column, i.e. data starts like 'item1, 19.1.2019,item2'.  But I'm not sure if this is always the case.

Comment: you should post a testable fragment of your data, obfuscated if necessary. If you're not sure if the data is consistently formatted, well, garbage in -- garbage out!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```awk
BEGIN { FS = "," }
{
        split($1, a, ".")
        timestamp = mktime(sprintf("%.4d %.2d %.2d 00 00 00", a[3], a[2], a[1]))
        day = strftime("%u", timestamp)
}

day >= 6
```

This GNU `awk` (or `mawk`) script would read the date in the format that you specified in the question from the first comma-delimited field.  It would split that field up and call `mktime()` to construct a Unix timestamp value corresponding to midnight on each read date.

It then uses `strftime()` with a format string, `%u`, that makes the function return the weekday as a decimal integer between 1 (Monday) and 7 (Sunday).

The last line tests the value for a weekend, and if that test succeeds, the current line is printed.  If you just want to print the line number, change that to `day >= 6 { print FNR }`.

You would run this like

```
$ awk -f script.awk myfile.csv
```

Note that this script requires either GNU `awk` or `mawk`, or the functions `mktime()` and `strftime()` may not be available.

Comment: There are at most 106 Sats and Suns in a year, and you probably have way more data rows than that. I would suggest reversing the test: BEGIN uses strftime to make a hash ssDate of all the dd.mm.yyyy that are the required dates, and you check each row like ($2 in ssDate).

Comment: @Paul_Pedant That would certainly be more efficient, but would require you to know the range of dates in advance.  This is sort of what the user is doing in the question, albeit using a regular expression.

Comment: The question was explicitly limited to 2019, as I read it. The technique does depend on the date range compared to the number of rows, but the days limit is only 25000. When I worked in SunOs (which had no date -d option) I made a one-off reference file that had every kind of date field (ISO weeks and all the rest) for 1900 to 2100, by running cal for every year. It simplified a lot of other scripts.